# Grid index Structure

Tags: java, indexing, datagrid, cmd, grid

*** ***

I learn a grid index structure. so far i have created data generator called data_gen.jar

here is the format output data from data_gen 
Each line consists of ID, x1, y1, x2, and y2 that represent a rectangle

[image]

let's say that this data store into text called input_data_set.txt
now my next steps are, first: make another program to do this

> ./gri -m page_capacity -l object_list_size -h -f input_data_set 
>   -m: Number of points in a disk page.
>   -l: Number of points can be stored in memory.
>   -h: Use Hilbert order to compute ordering number. Default is row
>   ordering.
>   -f: Input filename.

After executing the command,three files **gri.conf**, **gri.idx** and **gri.iof** must be produced.

in **grid.conf** we store the configurations 
For simplicity, we assume page size of the **gri.iof** file is sufficient to store **overflow points**. This implies you can drop some points
when the points number exceeds **capacity of a page** of the **gri.iof** file. One can also adjust the data-set to
prevent from too many overflow points.

---

here is the figure for more detail

[image]

then, After construction, use following command to enter an interactive mode
./gri -i [-c cache_size] -h

**I)nsert 

D)elete 

Q)uery/Index 

U)pdate** 
cmd> 
Users can type command to interact with the gri. Following is a simulation. 
./gri -i -c 4 -h 
cmd> I 4:8,9,8,9 
gri: Point 4 is inserted into cell(x, y). 
cmd> Q 4:8,9,8,9 
gri: Point 4 is stored at cell(x, y), page 2. 
gri: Page 2 includes points: 3, 4. 
gri-cache: 2, 3, 4, 5 #disk page number 
cmd> D 4:8,9,8,9 
gri: Point 4 is deleted from cell(x, y), page 2. 
gri: Page 2 includes points: 3. 
cmd> U 4:8,9,8,9 1,2,1,2 
gri: Point 4 is migrate from page 2 to page 0. 
gri-cache: 4, 5, 1, 0

in case, i'm doing in java..
does anyone could help me or guide me.. any reference would be great
i'm confusing for the next step, i have only succeed in data generator

here is some code

**GRI.java**

```
package gri;

import java.io.*;

public class GRI 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String strin="null";
        BufferedReader buf;
        int M=4,N=10000;
        double Sx=100,Sy=100;
        int method=1;
        int timestamp=1;

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of data:");
        buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        strin=buf.readLine();
        N=Integer.parseInt(strin);

        System.out.println("Please enter a page capacity (M):");
        strin=buf.readLine();
        M=Integer.parseInt(strin);

        System.out.println("Please enter Sx:");
        strin=buf.readLine();
        Sx=Double.parseDouble(strin);

        System.out.println("Please enter Sy:");
        strin=buf.readLine();
        Sy=Double.parseDouble(strin);
        System.out.println("N: "+N+" "+"M:"+M+" "+"Sx:"+Sx+" "+"Sy:"+Sy);

        int count_d=N;  //Record number of existing information

//      System.out.println("請選擇index方式:");
        System.out.println("1.row order");
        System.out.println("2.Z-Curve");
//      strin=buf.readLine();
//      method=Integer.parseInt(strin);

        System.out.println("Please enter K:");
        strin=buf.readLine();
        int k=Integer.parseInt(strin);

        System.out.println("Please X% of the point before entering as a query: ");
        strin=buf.readLine();
        int x=Integer.parseInt(strin);
        int query_num=N/100*x;
        System.out.println("query number: "+query_num);


        String temp=Integer.toString(N);
        int N_len=temp.length();
        temp="X";
        for(int i=0;i<N_len+15-1;i++)
        {
            temp=temp+"X";
        }

        double grid=0;
        int grid_i=0,cell=0;
        cell=(int)Math.ceil((double)N/M);   //至少需幾個cells  取大於的最小整數
        grid=Math.sqrt(cell);   // ? x ?  的?
        grid_i=(int)Math.ceil(grid);    // ? 取大於的最小整數    grid_i x grid_i
        int grid_z=1;
        if(method==2)
        {
            while(grid_z<grid_i)
            {
                grid_z*=2;
            }
            grid_i=grid_z;
        }
        System.out.println("至少需cell:"+cell+" "+"幾乘幾:"+grid_i+" x "+grid_i);

        double cellx=Sx/grid_i; //  一格的 x 分量
        double celly=Sy/grid_i; //  一格的 y 分量
        System.out.println("一格的 X 分量:"+cellx+" "+"一格的 Y 分量:"+celly);

        //輸出 設定檔
        FileWriter fw3 = new FileWriter("gri.conf");
        BufferedWriter bfw3 = new BufferedWriter(fw3);
        bfw3.write("size of data: "+N);
        bfw3.newLine();
        bfw3.write("page capacity: "+M);
        bfw3.newLine();
        bfw3.write("grid size: "+grid_i+" x "+grid_i);
        bfw3.newLine();
        bfw3.write("一格的 X 分量: "+cellx+" 一格的 Y 分量: "+celly);
        bfw3.newLine();
        bfw3.flush();
        fw3.close();        

        String str;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("stdout1.txt");
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fr);

        //orderfile空間
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("gri.idx");
        BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        //規劃overflow空間
        FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter("gri.iof");
        BufferedWriter bfw2 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);

        //開始規劃
        for(int i=0;i<grid_i*grid_i;i++)
        {
            String disk_p="#";
            for(int j=0;j<N_len-Integer.toString(i).length();j++)
                disk_p=disk_p+"0";
            disk_p=disk_p+Integer.toString(i);

            bfw.write(disk_p);
            bfw.newLine();
            bfw2.write(disk_p);
            bfw2.newLine();

            for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
            {
                bfw.write(temp);
                bfw.newLine();
                bfw2.write(temp);
                bfw2.newLine();
            }           
        }
        bfw.flush();
        fw.close();
        bfw2.flush();
        fw2.close();
//      System.out.println("orderfile & overlfow create");

        File file = new File("gri.idx");
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        File file2 = new File("gri.iof");
        RandomAccessFile raf2 = new RandomAccessFile(file2, "rw");

        //建index
        while( ( str=bfr.readLine() )!=null )   //從stdout.txt讀取
        {
            int ci=0,cj=0;  // 以 row ordered 的編號
            int disk_p=0;
            int overflow=0;
            String diskcon; //應放位置
            String[] str_arr = str.split(" ");  //  str_arr[0]=ID, str_arr[1]=Xlow , str_arr[2]=Ylow...
            String data=str_arr[0]+" "+str_arr[1]+" "+str_arr[2];

            ci=(int) Math.ceil( (Double.parseDouble(str_arr[1])/cellx) );
            cj=(int) Math.ceil( (Double.parseDouble(str_arr[2])/celly) );
//          System.out.println(ci+" "+cj);    
            disk_p=(cj-1)*grid_i+ci-1;  //DISK中的位置  -1因為從0開始

            if(method==2)       //以Z_ORDER的方式計算
                disk_p=cul_zorder(ci,cj);               

            //not need
            String pos = "#";
            for(int i=0;i<N_len-Integer.toString(disk_p).length();i++)
                pos=pos+"0";
            pos+=Integer.toString(disk_p);
            //not need

//          System.out.println(disk_p);

            raf.seek( ( N_len+1+2+ (temp.length()+2)*M )*disk_p + N_len+1+2 );  //搜尋區塊
            for(int i=0;i<M;i++)    //檢查此區塊是否已存M點
            {
                if((diskcon=raf.readLine()).equals(temp))
                {
                    raf.seek(raf.getFilePointer()-17-N_len);
                    raf.writeBytes(data);
                    for(int j=0;j<temp.length()-data.length();j++)
                        raf.writeBytes(" ");
                    break;
                }
                else
                    overflow++;
            }
            if(overflow==M) //已經存滿M個點  overflow
            {
                raf2.seek( ( N_len+1+2+ (temp.length()+2)*M )*disk_p + N_len+1+2 ); //搜尋區塊
                for(int i=0;i<M;i++)    //檢查此區塊是否已存M點
                {
                    if((diskcon=raf2.readLine()).equals(temp))
                    {
                        raf2.seek(raf2.getFilePointer()-17-N_len);
                        raf2.writeBytes(data);
                        for(int j=0;j<temp.length()-data.length();j++)
                            raf2.writeBytes(" ");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            raf.seek(0);    
            raf2.seek(0);
        }
        raf.close();
        raf2.close();
        fr.close();
        //成功建立index

        while( !(strin.equals("E")) )
        {
            File file3 = new File("gri.idx");
            RandomAccessFile raf3 = new RandomAccessFile(file3, "rw");
            File file4 = new File("gri.iof");
            RandomAccessFile raf4 = new RandomAccessFile(file4, "rw");
            System.out.println("Enter the command: ");
            System.out.println("I)nsert ");
            System.out.println("D)elete ");
            System.out.println("Q)uery");
            System.out.println("U)pdate to next time ");
            System.out.println("E)xit ");

            strin=buf.readLine();
            strin=strin.toUpperCase();
            String inc;
            switch(strin)
            {
                case "I":
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter xlow,ylow,xhigh,yhigh");
                    inc="null,";
                    inc=inc+buf.readLine();
                    String result[]=checkpoint(inc,raf3,raf4,M,grid_i,N_len,temp,cellx,celly,method);
                    count_d=Insert(inc,raf3,raf4,M,result,N_len,temp,count_d);
                    break;
                }
                case "D":
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter ID,xlow,ylow,xhigh,yhigh");
                    inc=buf.readLine();
                    String result[]=checkpoint(inc,raf3,raf4,M,grid_i,N_len,temp,cellx,celly,method);
                    if(result[0].equals("true"))
                    {
                        Delete(inc,raf3,raf4,M,result,N_len,temp);
                        System.out.println("Remove finished");
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("It does not exist at this point");
                    break;              
                }
                case "Q":
                {
//                  System.out.println("please enter ID,xlow,ylow,xhigh,yhigh");
                    inc=buf.readLine();
                    String result[]=checkpoint(inc,raf3,raf4,M,grid_i,N_len,temp,cellx,celly,method);
                    if(result[0].equals("true"))
                        System.out.println("The presence of this point");
                    else
                        System.out.println("It does not exist at this point");
//                  System.out.println("此點會被歸在cell: ("+result[1]+","+result[2]+")   ,會被放在: "+result[3]+" 區");
                    break;
                }
                case "U":
                {
                    if(timestamp<100)
                    {
                        String source_file="stdout"+Integer.toString(timestamp)+".txt";
                        timestamp++;
                        String update_file="stdout"+Integer.toString(timestamp)+".txt";

                        FileReader fr_s = new FileReader(source_file);
                        BufferedReader bfr_s = new BufferedReader(fr_s);

                        FileReader fr_u = new FileReader(update_file);
                        BufferedReader bfr_u = new BufferedReader(fr_u);

                        String str_s,str_u;
                        int temp_ID=1;
                        int count_fai=0;
                        while( ( str_s=bfr_s.readLine() )!=null )   //從source讀取 & update
                        {
                            String temp2[] = str_s.split(" ");
                            String everyID=Integer.toString(temp_ID);
                            temp_ID++;
                            inc=everyID+","+temp2[1]+","+temp2[2]+","+temp2[3]+","+temp2[4];
                            String ID[]=inc.split(",");
                            String result[]=checkpoint(inc,raf3,raf4,M,grid_i,N_len,temp,cellx,celly,method);
//                          System.out.println(everyID);
                            if(result[0].equals("true"))
                            {
                                Delete(inc,raf3,raf4,M,result,N_len,temp);                              
                                str_u=bfr_u.readLine();
                                String temp3[] = str_u.split(" ");
                                inc=everyID+","+temp3[1]+","+temp3[2]+","+temp3[3]+","+temp3[4];

                                result=checkpoint(inc,raf3,raf4,M,grid_i,N_len,temp,cellx,celly,method);
                                System.out.print("移動結果:");
                                Insert(inc,raf3,raf4,M,result,N_len,temp,count_d);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                str_u=bfr_u.readLine();
                                count_fai++;
//                              System.out.pruintln("不存在此點");
                            }

                        }
                        System.out.println("finish");
//                      System.out.println(count_fai);


                    }

//                  System.out.println("請輸入此點的ID,xlow,ylow,xhigh,yhigh");
//                  inc=buf.readLine();
//                  String ID[]=inc.split(",");
//                  String result[]=checkpoint(inc,raf3,raf4,M,grid_i,N_len,temp,cellx,celly,method);
//                  if(result[0].equals("true"))
//                  {
//                      Delete(inc,raf3,raf4,M,result,N_len,temp);
//                      System.out.println("要移動到?  輸入xlow,ylow,xhigh,yhigh");
//                      inc=ID[0]+","+buf.readLine();
//                      result=checkpoint(inc,raf3,raf4,M,grid_i,N_len,temp,cellx,celly,method);
//                      System.out.print("移動結果:");
//                      Insert(inc,raf3,raf4,M,result,N_len,temp,count_d);
//                  }
//                      
//                  else
//                      System.out.println("不存在此點");
                    break;      
                }
                case "E":
                {
                    System.out.println("exit... thanks .. bye..");
                    break;
                }
            }

            raf3.close();
            raf4.close();

        }
    }

    static int Insert(String P, RandomAccessFile raf, RandomAccessFile raf2,int M, String result[], int N_len, String temp,int count_d) throws IOException
    {
        int disk_p=Integer.parseInt(result[3]);
        String diskcon,data;
        String[] P_pos = P.split(",");
        raf.seek( ( N_len+1+2+ (temp.length()+2)*M )*disk_p + N_len+1+2 );
        raf2.seek( ( N_len+1+2+ (temp.length()+2)*M )*disk_p + N_len+1+2 );
        int overflow=0;

        for(int i=0;i<M;i++)    //檢查此區塊是否存了M個點
        {           
            if((diskcon=raf.readLine()).equals(temp))
            {
                if(P_pos[0].equals("null"))
                {
                    count_d++;
                    data=Integer.toString(count_d)+": "+P_pos[1]+" "+P_pos[2];
                }
                else
                    data=P_pos[0]+": "+P_pos[1]+" "+P_pos[2];

                raf.seek(raf.getFilePointer()-17-N_len);
                raf.writeBytes(data);
                for(int j=0;j<temp.length()-data.length();j++)
                    raf.writeBytes(" ");
                System.out.println("成功,"+P_pos[0]+" 在orderfile "+result[3]+"區");
                return count_d;
            }
            else
                overflow++;
        }
        if(overflow==M) //已經存滿M個點  overflow
        {
            overflow=0;
            for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
            {
                if((diskcon=raf2.readLine()).equals(temp))
                {
                    if(P_pos[0].equals("null"))
                    {
                        count_d++;
                        data=Integer.toString(count_d)+": "+P_pos[1]+" "+P_pos[2];
                    }
                    else
                        data=P_pos[0]+": "+P_pos[1]+" "+P_pos[2];

                    raf2.seek(raf2.getFilePointer()-17-N_len);
                    raf2.writeBytes(data);
                    for(int j=0;j<temp.length()-data.length();j++)
                        raf2.writeBytes(" ");
                    System.out.println("成功, 在Overflow "+result[3]+"區");
                    return count_d;
                }
                else
                    overflow++;
            }           
        }
        if(overflow==M)
            System.out.println("都滿囉，丟掉了");
        return count_d;

    }

    static void Delete(String P, RandomAccessFile raf, RandomAccessFile raf2,int M, String result[], int N_len, String temp) throws IOException
    {
        int disk_p=Integer.parseInt(result[3]);
        String diskcon;
        String[] P_pos = P.split(",");
        raf.seek( ( N_len+1+2+ (temp.length()+2)*M )*disk_p + N_len+1+2 );
        raf2.seek( ( N_len+1+2+ (temp.length()+2)*M )*disk_p + N_len+1+2 );
        P_pos[0]=P_pos[0]+":";

        for(int i=0;i<M;i++)    //檢查此區塊(orderfile)是否存點
        {
            diskcon=raf.readLine();
            if(!diskcon.equals(temp))
            {
                String[] pos = diskcon.split(" ");
                if(pos[1].equals(P_pos[1]) && pos[2].equals(P_pos[2]) && pos[0].equals(P_pos[0]))   //找到了
                {
                    raf.seek(raf.getFilePointer()-17-N_len);
                    raf.writeBytes(temp);
                    raf.writeBytes("\r\n");
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<M;i++)    //檢查此區塊(overflow)是否存點
        {
            diskcon=raf2.readLine();
            if(!diskcon.equals(temp))
            {
                String[] pos = diskcon.split(" ");
                if(pos[1].equals(P_pos[1]) && pos[2].equals(P_pos[2]) && pos[0].equals(P_pos[0]))   //找到了
                {
                    raf2.seek(raf2.getFilePointer()-17-N_len);
                    raf2.writeBytes(temp);
                    raf2.writeBytes("\r\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static String[] checkpoint(String P, RandomAccessFile raf, RandomAccessFile raf2, int M, int grid_i, int N_len, String temp, double cellx, double celly,int method) throws IOException
    {
        String result[]={"","","",""};
        String diskcon;
        String[] P_pos = P.split(",");
        int ci=(int) Math.ceil( (Double.parseDouble(P_pos[1])/cellx) );
        int cj=(int) Math.ceil( (Double.parseDouble(P_pos[2])/celly) );
        int disk_p=(cj-1)*grid_i+ci-1;
        if(method==2)
            disk_p=cul_zorder(ci,cj);

        result[1]=Integer.toString(ci);
        result[2]=Integer.toString(cj);
        result[3]=Integer.toString(disk_p);
        if(P_pos[0].equals("null"))
        {
            result[0]="null";
            return result;
        }
        P_pos[0]=P_pos[0]+":";

        raf.seek( ( N_len+1+2+ (temp.length()+2)*M )*disk_p + N_len+1+2 );
        raf2.seek( ( N_len+1+2+ (temp.length()+2)*M )*disk_p + N_len+1+2 );
        for(int i=0;i<M;i++)    //檢查ORDERFILE是否存此點
        {
//          System.out.println("搜尋orderfile區塊");
            diskcon=raf.readLine();
//          System.out.println(diskcon);
            if(!diskcon.equals(temp))
            {
                String[] pos = diskcon.split(" ");
                if(pos[1].equals(P_pos[1]) && pos[2].equals(P_pos[2]))
                {
                    if(P_pos[0].equals(pos[0]))
                    {
                        System.out.println("在orderfile "+result[3]+"區");
                        result[0]="true";   //return true;
                        return result;
                    }               
                }
            }                   
        }
        for(int i=0;i<M;i++)    //檢查OVERFLOW是否存此點
        {
            diskcon=raf2.readLine();
//          System.out.println(diskcon);
            if(!diskcon.equals(temp))
            {
                String[] pos = diskcon.split(" ");
                if(pos[1].equals(P_pos[1]) && pos[2].equals(P_pos[2]))
                {
                    if(P_pos[0].equals(pos[0]))
                    {
                        System.out.println("在overflow "+result[3]+"區");
                        result[0]="true";   //return true;
                        return result;
                    }                   
                }
            }           
        }
        result[0]="false";  //return false;
        return result;
    }

    static int cul_zorder(int ci,int cj)
    {
        String b_ci=null,b_cj=null;
        int x=ci-1,y=cj-1,disk_p;

        if(x==0)
            b_ci=b_ci+"0";
        if(y==0)
            b_cj=b_cj+"0";
        while(x>0)
        {
            b_ci=b_ci+Integer.toString(x%2);
            x=x/2;
        }
        while(y>0)
        {
            b_cj=b_cj+Integer.toString(y%2);
            y=y/2;
        }
        if(b_ci.length()>b_cj.length())
            for(int i=b_ci.length()-b_cj.length();i>0;i--)
                b_cj=b_cj+"0";
        else if(b_ci.length()<b_cj.length())
            for(int i=b_cj.length()-b_ci.length();i>0;i--)
                b_ci=b_ci+"0";

        String zdisk="nu";

        for(int i=b_cj.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(b_ci.charAt(i)=='0')
                zdisk=zdisk+"0";
            else if(b_ci.charAt(i)=='1')
                zdisk=zdisk+"1";

            if(b_cj.charAt(i)=='0')
                zdisk=zdisk+"0";
            else if(b_cj.charAt(i)=='1')
                zdisk=zdisk+"1";
        }

        int two_d=1,dig=0;

        for(int i=zdisk.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(zdisk.charAt(i)=='1')
                dig=dig+two_d;
            two_d=two_d*2;
        }

        disk_p=dig;
        return disk_p;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: thank you, i have edited already, the gri.java is all task we do in single code..